# Ingnoring particular record while execution in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I am getting rows like blow.

```
 date            Week          Total

'2018-01-10'      '00',       '104072'

'2018-01-10',     '48',         '2'

'2018-01-10',     '00',        '61'

'2018-01-10',     '48',        '3'
```

Here every time i am execution the query I am getting the week 00 like above
Now I want to ignore that particular record '00' while executing the query.
Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems odd that your numbers are strings.

Comment: Try `WHERE Week != '00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's a `VARCHAR` column:

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE Week != '00'
```

It's generally better to store numbers as `INT` for a variety of reasons.